# Aplicar duas funções ao .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Não entendo muito bem o .htacces, mas eu o utilizo para forçar a navegação do meu site para o **https**, agora estou tentando implementar um código para retirar o **.html** da URL, já havia feito isso, mas quando eu junto os dois não funciona.

Forçar https:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Retirar .html da URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Como eu faço para os dois funcionarem juntos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando o RewriteRule corresponde, a flag [**`[L]`**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) (*LAST*) pára de processar outras regras.
Tem que removê-la da primeira regra.

```python
RewriteEngine On

#Forçar https
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT}      ^80$
RewriteRule     ^                   https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]

#Retirar .html da URL
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ^(.*)\.html$        $1        [NC,R=301]
```

E, após o redirecionamento, se quiser reescrever todos os requests sem `.html` para a página com `.html`, pode adicionar:

```
#Reescrever o .html (adicionado internamente, o usuário não o vê)    
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ^((?:[^.]*|.*[^.]{5})[./])$   $1.html
```

Comment: Mas o ".html" ainda continua mesmo tirando o [L] do de cima.

Comment: Como assim não existe? achei que isso iria tirar o ".html" da URL eu tinha feito algo assim, deve ter me enganado então, desculpe.

Comment: @Bretone `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` define uma condição para executar a regra somente quando o arquivo (`-f`) não está presente na pasta. Você pode remover essa condição para verificar se a regra está funcionando, mas acho que isso lhe dará um 404.